# Matplotlib Legend for Scatter with custom colours

Tags: python, charts, matplotlib

I'm a bit of newbie at this and am trying to create a scatter chart with custom bubble sizes and colours.  The chart displays fine but how do I get a legend saying what the colours refer to.  This is as far as I've got:

```
inc = []
out = []
bal = []
col = []

fig=Figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)

inc = (30000,20000,70000)
out = (80000,30000,40000)
bal = (12000,10000,6000)
col = (1,2,3)
leg = ('proj1','proj2','proj3')

ax.scatter(inc, out, s=bal, c=col)
ax.axis([0, 100000, 0, 100000])

ax.set_xlabel('income', fontsize=20)
ax.set_ylabel('Expenditure', fontsize=20)
ax.set_title('Project FInancial Positions %s' % dt)
ax.grid(True)
canvas=FigureCanvas(fig)
response=HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')
canvas.print_png(response)
```

This thread was helpful, but couldn't get it to solve my problem: [Matplotlib: Legend not displayed properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872397/matplotlib-legend-not-displayed-properly)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe this [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Weight_Growth_of_RN_First_Rate_Line-of-Battle_Ships_1630-1875.svg) is helpful.

In general, the items in the legend are related with some kind of *plotted object*. The `scatter` function/method treats all circles as a single object, see:

```
print type(ax.scatter(...))
```

Thus the solution is to create multiple objects. Hence, calling `scatter` multiple times.

Unfortunately, newer version of matplotlib seem not to use a rectangle in the legend. Thus the legend will contain very large circles, since you increased the size of your scatter plot objects.

The legend function as a `markerscale` keyword argument to control the size of legend markers, but it seems to be broken.

**Update:**

The [Legend guide](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/legend_guide.html) recommends using [Proxy Artist](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/legend_guide.html#using-proxy-artist) in similar cases. The [Color API](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/colors_api.html) explains valid `fc` values.

```
p1 = Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc="b")
p2 = Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc="g")
p3 = Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc="r")
legend((p1, p2, p3), ('proj1','proj2','proj3'))
```

To get the colors used previously in a plot, use the above example like:

```
pl1, = plot(x1, y1, '.', alpha=0.1, label='plot1')
pl2, = plot(x2, y2, '.', alpha=0.1, label='plot2')
p1 = Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc=pl1.get_color())
p2 = Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc=pl2.get_color())
legend((p1, p2), (pl1.get_label(), pl2.get_label()), loc='best')
```

This example will make a plot like:

[image: Matplotlib with custom legend]

Comment: Good solution, even if it doesn't work because of the broken markerscale.

Comment: That example is very helpful.  Have to go and do proper work for a while but will come back to it this evening.